# Why can't Facebook share pick up my Firebase storage image file?

Tags: html, facebook, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following button:

```
 <a class="btn btn-social btn-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1732jjjjjjj
                &redirect_uri={{statusUrl}}
                &link=https://sitename.com/{{statusUrl}}
                &name={{isTitle}}
                &picture=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rrrr.appspot.com/o/eWebcontent%2Fc0638f6c65d2aa5c81f9ef820531eda2?alt=media&token=93c157e6-05ec-4efe-8ca5-86942cfac742
                &caption=www.sitename.com
                &author=Author
                &description={{statusDesc}}.
                &properties={text:’value1′,key2:’value2′}
                &actions={name:’I LOVE u’,link:’https://www.sitename.com’}&&
  display=popup">
```

Everything else works fine, except that the image doesn't show up.
It just shows a blank space.

It's a one page site, so there is not much I can do with the open graph meta tags.

Why isn't facebook able to show the image?

Comment: You need to properly URL-encode the parameter value.

Comment: The fun thing is that it actually *is* properly encoded, Facebook just assumes that it isn't and thus re-encodes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the issue here has to do with websites handling character escaping differently.

Your image is named `eWebcontent%2Fc0638f6c65d2aa5c81f9ef820531eda2` since Firebase Storage has encoded the `/` as `%2F`. I assume that Facebook (and some other sites) try to re-percent encode the `%` character (`%25`), meaning that Facebook is actually looking for an image named `...%252F...`, and not finding it. Unfortunately, I can't seem to reproduce this using other percent encoded characters, so I'm confused if it's somehow just an issue with `/` or what.

The current solution is to simply not place `/`s in your URLs (e.g. just name your image `c0638f6c65d2aa5c81f9ef820531eda2` or something.

Comment: Any news on this?