# how to convert firebase download url to base64 image?

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-storage, socialshare

I am using ionic and firebase. I am trying to send the img url to facebook shareing using the Ionic Cordova social sharing plugin.

```
share(message, subject, file, url)
```

When I send the img url from my database it says url not valid. Therefore I am trying to convert the download url to base64 image so I can share it. Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks for your helps in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Facebook share pick up my Firebase storage image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477174/why-cant-facebook-share-pick-up-my-firebase-storage-image-file)

Comment: Percent encoding on the URL is the issue here, per the issue I flagged this as a dupe of.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Thx for flagging it as duplicate..i get to see the reason that you mentioned in that question. that means i just have to remove the '/' and it will work??

Comment: Either remove it or un-percent encode it (leave it as a `/` instead of as `%2F`). You'll have to do the same with all percent encoded characters.